# Is it possible to get notified when a package is loaded within another package or function?

Tags: r

I am writing a function for my package, and its goal is to get notified when a certain package is loaded so that it could do something to respond to the package loading. It's similar to `.onLoad()` except that it's the response for other packages.

Is it possible to do this in R?

Comment: You want to get notified when someone else uses your package? If so please read this fortunes::fortune("call home") **It seems to me against the spirit of Open Source software to attempt to monitor distribution. We could ask
R to 'call home' on first use (in the way e.g. pine does) but I suspect many users would find that
objectionable.
   -- Brian D. Ripley (in a discussion about trying to estimate the number of R users)
      R-help (April 2004)**

Comment: You can check which packages are loaded with `(.packages())`. This can be combined with `grep()` to obtain information whether a specific package is loaded.

Comment: @Thierry, no, I want to get notified when other packages are loaded .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out by using `setHook()`.

```
setHook(packageEvent("pkg", "attach"),
    function(...) {
      message('hooked')
    } )
```